# Sort character-delimited string of variable length

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

How does one sort a character-delimited string of a variable length?

I'd like to sort this table

```
number   | make
=========|=========
11280-08 | bmw
13920-08 | audi
44630-08 | audi
1741-08  | mercedes
03-05    | audi
40093-08 | audi
332-04   | bmw
```

so that first ascend the suffixes `-00` and then the prefixes `0000` within each suffix group:

```
number   | make
=========|=========
332-04   | bmw
03-05    | audi
1741-08  | mercedes
11280-08 | bmw
13920-08 | audi
40093-08 | audi
44630-08 | audi
```

I'm running this query

```
select * from mytable
order by right(number,2),number asc
```

but I get this

```
number   | make
=========|=========
332-04   | bmw
03-05    | audi
11280-08 | bmw
13920-08 | audi
1741-08  | mercedes
40093-08 | audi
44630-08 | audi
```

Note how `1741-08` follows `13920-08` while it should precede it.

Comment: Why have you combined multiple separate values into one field?

Comment: You mean why not store the prefixes and suffixes apart? I don't know. I didn't design that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varchars will sort alphabetically: `(1,11,2,21,3,...)`  If you want numeric order, cast the prefix as an integer.

```
select * from mytable
order by
  right(number,2)
 ,CAST(LEFT(number,LEN(number)-3) AS int)
```

Comment: You've nailed it for me, Anon. Muchas gracias. My mistake was, as you've pointed out, expecting varchars to sort as ints.

Answer (score 1):

Add missing zero to shorter number so they come first. This way, when sorting, they all have the same length.  Here we assume biggest number have 8 characters

```
select * 
from mytable
order by REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(number)) + number
```